# Can you add rows to gridview from strings?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

I want to make a gridview with 4 columns. (Checkbox, Hyperlink name Title, Dynamic name Price, Dynamic named ASIN#)

I want to be able to add new rows to the gridview from three different strings.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
Private Sub displayData(title As String, cost As String, asin As String)
```

Is it possible to even add new data to the gridview with these strings.  I've looked all around online and most things deal with databases.  I'm also not 100% sure how to initialize at gridview.

Thanks for any insight you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a peice of code to add the row to the datagrid.

```
Dim row As String()

row = New String() {title, cost, asin}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It says that Add isn't a member of GridViewRowCollection :(

Comment: Do I need to have an Imports statement in the vb file?